# CSS FPS view flickering and freezing

Tags: javascript, css, 3d

I'm trying to make a basic FPS view using CSS.

Here's a demo of what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/w8q7xtmL/

In particular, movement is as simple as detecting keypresses, then:

```
// "self" is if the player object
requestAnimationFrame(step);
function step() {
  if( keys[37]) self.direction += 2;
  if( keys[39]) self.direction -= 2;
  if( keys[38]) {
    self.x += Math.cos(self.direction/180*Math.PI) * 4;
    self.y -= Math.sin(self.direction/180*Math.PI) * 4;
  }
  if( keys[40]) {
    self.x -= Math.cos(self.direction/180*Math.PI) * 4;
    self.y += Math.sin(self.direction/180*Math.PI) * 4;
  }

  self.camera.style.transform = "rotateX(90deg) rotateZ("+(self.direction-90)+"deg) translate(-"+self.x+"px,-"+self.y+"px)";

  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

This works quite well, but there are a couple of issues.

1. Sometimes, elements don't stack correctly. The floor will be visible when walls should be blocking it from view, for instance.
2. Other times, the view will freeze completely, despite there being no errors in the console or anything that would indicate failure. It just... stops. Sometimes I can get it un-stuck by trying to move around a bit to "unstick" it, but other times I just have to reload the page.

Are there any discernible errors in my approach, or is the state of 3D transforms just not there yet for this kind of thing?

For the record, in case it matters, I'm developing with Google Chrome 49.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, as I'm no games programmer; but why aren't you using the HTML5 [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage)?

Comment: @Brett Partly because down the line I will be wanting these walls to have HTML features, such as buttons, text, or even have the walls themselves be canvases.

Comment: Interesting concept. Perhaps the issue may be that the rendering engine of the browser is the culprit here? I don't think HTML and CSS rendering was designed to handle such a use case as yours. But that's just my guess.

Comment: Yeah, it's seeming that way. It's a shame though. Can you imagine a game dev company's website itself being a game where the walls of the area are the site's pages? The best part with it being CSS is that you can just toggle a class and suddenly all the panel that make up the wall become simple 2d `<div>`s!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe I missed this.

Before:

```
self.camera.style.transform = "rotateX(90deg) rotateZ("+(self.direction-90)+"deg)
             translate(-"+self.x+"px,-"+self.y+"px)";
```

After:

```
self.camera.style.transform = "rotateX(90deg) rotateZ("+(self.direction-90)+"deg)
             translate("+(-self.x)+"px,"+(-self.y)+"px)";
```

Because, funnily enough, when `self.x` is negative, you get `translate(--12px,0px)` which is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you are detecting keys in a loop. 
Instead, use this:

```
var rotval = 0;

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    key = e.keyCode
    if(key === "left")
    {
    rotval = 1;
    }
    }, true);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    key = e.keyCode
    if(key === "left")
    {
    rotval = 0;
    }
    }, true);
```

then just add a variable to the loop function and when it is more or less than 0, it moves or rotates the camera!

```
    function loop()
    {
    camera.rotation.y += rotval
camera.position.x //and so on    
}
    setInterval(loop,30)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm sure I've never seen an FPS where you have to press Up repeatedly to keep moving forwards...

Comment: you need to add it to a loop.

Comment: "I believe it is because you are detecting keys in a loop. Instead, use this:" -- so... which is it? Use a loop or don't use a loop?

Comment: Yes, I will try to edit your code for you if I have the time :)

Comment: Oh, sorry nice pickup :)